# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a embedded sql database?

Tags: database-design, performance, export, load-balancing, embedded

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using an embedded SQL database instead of MySQL server? I am a web developer and I'm planning to develop an application for the shop, without investing my time to learn the Desktop application I wanna convert my web app to work as a desktop while embedding application server and database.
I was wondering if there is anything I should know about before moving forward.
I like the zero configuration and management part of embedded databases, but what are some disadvantages?

Answer (score 2):

Embedded SQL engine has a great advantage if your application can't or shouldn't connect to the server over the net and you can't setup the local SQL server on the LAN. Then you can use the embedded engine that allows you to use the same SQL code in absence of the client-server environment. Also the advantage of the embedded engine that you'll get all the advantages of the RDBMS like complex search with a SQL code and ACIDity of data. That is the reason SQLite is used by browsers, for example.

If the single instance of application is working with the single instance of the DB and vice versa, and the RDBMS is more suitable/familiar than other data storages then embedded SQL definitely is an option.